# Is there a way to authenticate user with Google without navigating outside your iOS App?

Tags: ios, google-plus

So I used the [Google+ SDK](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started) to allow users to authenticate themselves using their Google+ accounts. I got that done put my app for review and it got rejected because the user is navigated outside the app to be able to sign in or sign up.

The flow for the Authentication Process is

1. User taps on the Google+ button.                    **App in Control**
2. Check if Google Plus app is installed on device.               **Google SDK in Control**
3. Navigate to Google Plus App (if exists)            **Google SDK in Control**
   or to Safari Browser
4. Authenticate user and Authorize the app         **Google SDK in Control**
5. Return to app with user token                          **Google SDK in Control**
6. Save user token                                               **App in Control**
7. Navigate to First Screen                                  **App in Control**

The app has been rejected because " The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for creating an account or logging in, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able to create an account or log in without opening Safari first". This reason for rejection is part of the flow for which The Google SDK is in control. This makes it very difficult to solve the "issue".

So is there a way to authenticate with Google without having the user to be navigated to Safari of Google Plus App?

Comment: Checkout the [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=900#c46) regarding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this pretty easily using the [Google Identity SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/).

The following snippet should give you the gist of how you could configure the SDK in your app delegate to use a Webview for Sign-in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  NSError* configureError;
  [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
  NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);

  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithBrowser = NO;
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;

  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
  return YES;
}
```